# XForms: how to have radio buttons of the same group appear in many td's / rows in a grid?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I need radio buttons of the same group to be in more than 1 cell. How to achieve this ?

I have an `<fr:grid>` and I need a `<xf:select1>` having its items (I'm working with an itemset) to be in many `<xh:tr>` and `<xh:td>`

Edit: code sample:

```
   <fr:grid>
       <xh:tr>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:select1 id="ZSledig-control" appearance="full" bind="ZSledig-bind">
                   <xf:label ref="$form-resources/ZSledig/label"/>
                   <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/ZSledig/hint"/>
                   <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                   <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/ZSledig/item">
                       <xf:label ref="label"/>
                       <xf:value ref="value"/>
                   </xf:itemset>
               </xf:select1>
           </xh:td>
           <xh:td/>
           <xh:td/>
           <xh:td/>
       </xh:tr>
       <xh:tr>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:select1 id="ZSverheiratet-control" appearance="full" bind="ZSverheiratet-bind">
                   <xf:label ref="$form-resources/ZSverheiratet/label"/>
                   <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/ZSverheiratet/hint"/>
                   <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                   <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/ZSverheiratet/item">
                       <xf:label ref="label"/>
                       <xf:value ref="value"/>
                   </xf:itemset>
               </xf:select1>
           </xh:td>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:input id="control-39-control" bind="control-39-bind">
                   <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-39/label"/>
                   <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-39/hint"/>
                   <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
               </xf:input>
           </xh:td>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:select1 id="ZSPartnerschaft-control" appearance="full" bind="ZSPartnerschaft-bind">
                   <xf:label ref="$form-resources/ZSPartnerschaft/label"/>
                   <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/ZSPartnerschaft/hint"/>
                   <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                   <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/ZSPartnerschaft/item">
                       <xf:label ref="label"/>
                       <xf:value ref="value"/>
                   </xf:itemset>
               </xf:select1>
           </xh:td>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:input id="control-11-control" bind="control-11-bind">
                   <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-11/label"/>
                   <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-11/hint"/>
                   <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
               </xf:input>
           </xh:td>
       </xh:tr>
    </fr:grid>
```

In the code above, I need all xf:select1 objects to be the same one. but with it's items in differents cells of the grid. The goal is to have a form looking as what you see in this  picture.[image: form sample]

Comment: What are your namespaces, can you include some more code to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you think such layout is possible ? The thing is, I need an input field corresponding to each radio button. The checkboxes you see in the picture are now radio buttons in my orbeon form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible with Form Builder: each cell must hold a control which points to different data, and the controls are unrelated.

If you want to hack, however, you can do that, but at your own risk, as Form Builder won't know about your changes.

I put an example [here](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/7538232):

- I modified the second `xf:select1` to point to the same bind as the first `xf:select1`
- I added an `xxf:group="my-group"` attribute on each `xf:select1`

Comment: FormBuilder seems not having problems with it. I also tried to update the control's properties in FB, then save the form, FB does not clear nor reset the modified binding. You saved my day.

Comment: Note that pointing to the same binding is enough. You don't have to use the xxf:group, it is done automatically when the control's bindings are the same. And FB runs into trouble when you specify more than one xxf:group in a form.